# A problem of compatibility between titlesec/titleps and biblatex

Tags: biblatex, titlesec

I recently met a problem when trying to format headers and footers of the bibliography with `titlesec/titleps`, and I can't understand what's happening.

More precisely, if I change the page style just before `\printbibliography` using one of the standard page styles (empty, plain, for instance), the page style does change accordingly. If I try a custom pagestyle defined with `titleps`, the page style also changes, but the default page style also seems to be used, as is demonstrated by the following code, where the page style for even pages is `left side: page no, right side: Bibliography in boldface`.

I'd be very grateful for any help solving this problem.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper] {book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{makeidx, amsfonts}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}

\usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=authortitle]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Qbiblio.bib}

\makeindex

\newcommand\rr{\mathbb{R}}
\newpagestyle{bibps}{%
\sethead[\thepage][][\bfseries Bibliography]{\bfseries Bibliography}{}{\thepage}
\setfoot{}{}{}
}%
%%
\newpagestyle{idxps}{%
\sethead[\thepage][][\scshape Index]{\scshape Index}{}{\thepage}
\setfoot{}{}{}
}%

\begin{document}

\chapter{A First Chapter}

\[ \bar{D}\mu(x) = \lim_{r\to 0}\bar{\Delta}_{r}(x) = \inf_{r}\,\sup\Bigl\{\frac{\mu(E)}{m(E)}; x \in E, \delta E < r \Bigr\} . \]%

\chapter{A Second Chapter}

\lipsum[1-10]

\cite{Rudin1,Rudin2}

 \cleardoublepage
\nocite{*}
\pagestyle{bibps}
\printbibliography

\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{idxps}
\printindex

\clearpage
\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

.bib file:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8


@Book{Arnold,
  Title                    = {Méthodes mathématiques de la mécanique classique},
  Author                   = {Vladimir Arnold},
  Date                     = {1976},
  Publisher                = {Éditions Mir},
  Owner                    = {Bernard},
  Timestamp                = {2015.12.16}
}

@Book{DunSchw,
  Title                    = {Linear Operators, Part II},
  Author                   = {Nelson Dunford and Jacob T. G. Schwartz},
  Date                     = {1963},
  Publisher                = {Interscience Publishers},
  Owner                    = {Bernard},
  Timestamp                = {2015.12.16}
}

@Book{Hall,
  Title                    = {Quantum Theory for Mathematicians},
  Author                   = {Brian C. Hall},
  Date                     = {2013},
  Publisher                = {Springer},
  Owner                    = {Bernard},
  Timestamp                = {2015.12.16}
}

@Book{Jordan,
  Title                    = {Linear Operators for Quantum Mechanics},
  Author                   = {Thomas F. Jordan},
  Date                     = {2009},
  Publisher                = {Dover Publications, Inc.},
  Owner                    = {Bernard},
  Timestamp                = {2015.12.16}
}

@Book{Khoan,
  Title                    = {Distributions, analyse de Fourier, opérateurs aux dérivées partielles},
  Author                   = {Vo-Khac Khoan},
  Date                     = {1972},
  Publisher                = {Vuibert},
  Volume                   = {1},
  Owner                    = {Bernard},
  Timestamp                = {2015.12.16}
}

@Book{Lal,
  Title                    = {Comprenons-nous vraiment la mécanique quantique ?},
  Author                   = {Franck Laloë},
  Date                     = {2011},
  Publisher                = {EDP Sciences},
  Owner                    = {Bernard},
  Timestamp                = {2015.12.16}
}

@Book{Neu,
  Title                    = {Mathematische Grundlagen des Quantummechanick},
  Author                   = {John von Neumann},
  Date                     = {1996},
  Edition                  = {2},
  Publisher                = {Springer},
  Langid                   = {german},
  Owner                    = {Bernard},
  Timestamp                = {2015.12.16}
}

@Book{ReedSim,
  Title                    = {Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics},
  Author                   = {Michael Reed and Barry G. Simon},
  Date                     = {1972},
  Publisher                = {Academic Press},
  Owner                    = {Bernard},
  Timestamp                = {2015.12.16}
}

@Book{Rudin1,
  Title                    = {Analyse réelle et complexe},
  Author                   = {Walter Rudin},
  Date                     = {1980},
  Publisher                = {Masson},
  Owner                    = {Bernard},
  Timestamp                = {2015.12.16}
}

@Book{Rudin2,
  Title                    = {Functional Analysis},
  Author                   = {Walter Rudin},
  Date                     = {1991},
  Edition                  = {2},
  Publisher                = {McGraw-Hill, Inc.},
  Langid                    ={british},
  Owner                    = {Bernard},
  Timestamp                = {2015.12.16}
}

@Book{schwartz2,
  author =    {Laurent Schwartz},
  title =     {Théorie des distributions},
  year =      {1966},
  publisher = {Hermann},
  owner =     {Bernard},
  timestamp = {2016.01.07}
}

@Book{schwartz,
  author =    {Laurent Schwartz},
  title =     {Topologie générale et Analyse fonctionnelle},
  date =      {1970},
  publisher = {Hermann},
  owner =     {Bernard},
  timestamp = {2015.12.16}
}

@Book{VladVlad,
  Title                    = {Distributions en physique mathématique},
  Author                   = {V. Vladimirov},
  Date                     = {1979},
  Location                 = {Moscou},
  Publisher                = {Éditions Mir. Moscou, 1979},
  Owner                    = {Bernard},
  Timestamp                = {2015.12.16}
}

@Book{Wein,
  Title                    = {Lectures on Quantum Mechanics},
  Author                   = {Steven Weinberg},
  Date                     = {2013},
  Publisher                = {Cambridge University Press},
  Owner                    = {Bernard},
  Timestamp                = {2015.12.16}
}

@Article{Wigner,
  Title                    = {On Unitary Representations of the Inhomogeneous Lorentz Group},
  Author                   = {Eugene P. Wigner},
  Date                     = {1939},
  Journaltitle             = {Ann. Math.},
  Number                   = {1},
  Pages                    = {149-204},
  Series                   = {2},
  Volume                   = {40},
  Owner                    = {Bernard},
  Timestamp                = {2015.12.16}
}

@Book{Yo,
  author =    {Kôsaku Yosida},
  title =     {Functional Analysis},
  date =      {1974},
  series =    {Grundlehren der mathematischen Wissenschaften},
  number =    {123},
  publisher = {Springer},
  owner =     {Bernard},
  timestamp = {2015.12.16}
}
```

.ind file:

```
\begin{theindex}

  \item \IeC {\'e}galit\IeC {\'e} de Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff, 107
  \item \IeC {\'e}quation de Schr\IeC {\"o}dinger, 104, 109
  \item \IeC {\'e}tat d'un syst\IeC {\`e}me, 99

  \indexspace

  \item alg\IeC {\`e}bre de Banach, 134
  \item alg\IeC {\`e}bre de Banach semi-simple, 138

  \indexspace

  \item borne essentielle, 15

  \indexspace

  \item crochet de deux op\IeC {\'e}rateurs, 107

  \indexspace

  \item d\IeC {\'e}riv\IeC {\'e}e au sens des distributions, 68, 142
  \item d\IeC {\'e}riv\IeC {\'e}e d'une mesure complexe, 7
  \item d\IeC {\'e}riv\IeC {\'e}e de Radon, 5
  \item distribution, 142

  \indexspace

  \item effondrement de la fonction d'onde, 102
  \item espaces spectraux, 24

  \indexspace

  \item famille substantielle d'ouverts, 7
  \item fermeture auto-adjointe, 54
  \item fermeture d'un op\IeC {\'e}rateur, 53
  \item fonction \IeC {\`a} variation born\IeC {\'e}e , 9
  \item fonction absolument continue , 9
  \item fonctions \IeC {\`a} d\IeC {\'e}croissance rapide, 147

  \indexspace

  \item g\IeC {\'e}n\IeC {\'e}rateur infinit\IeC {\'e}simal, 89

  \indexspace

  \item homomorphisme complexe, 135

  \indexspace

  \item id\IeC {\'e}al, id\IeC {\'e}al maximal, 136
  \item image essentielle , 15
  \item incertitude, 115
  \item int\IeC {\'e}grale de Bochner, 163
  \item involution, 134

  \indexspace

  \item lemme de Du Bois-Reymond, 144

  \indexspace

  \item mesure complexe, 3
  \item mesure complexe d\IeC {\'e}rivable, 7
  \item mesure complexe r\IeC {\'e}guli\IeC {\`e}re, 4
  \item mesure positive r\IeC {\'e}guli\IeC {\`e}re, 3
  \item mesure spectrale, 24
  \item mesures \IeC {\'e}trang\IeC {\`e}res, 4

  \indexspace

  \item norme d'une mesure complexe, 3

  \indexspace

  \item op\IeC {\'e}rateur \IeC {\'e}nergie potentielle, 60
  \item op\IeC {\'e}rateur \IeC {\`a} trace, 38
  \item op\IeC {\'e}rateur adjoint d'un op\IeC {\'e}rateur non born\IeC {\'e},
        50
  \item op\IeC {\'e}rateur compact, 30
  \item op\IeC {\'e}rateur de Hilbert-Schmidt, 42, 121
  \item op\IeC {\'e}rateur de quantification, 65
  \item op\IeC {\'e}rateur de Schr\IeC {\"o}dinger, 72
  \item op\IeC {\'e}rateur dens\IeC {\'e}ment d\IeC {\'e}fini, 50
  \item op\IeC {\'e}rateur essentiellement auto-adjoint, 54
  \item op\IeC {\'e}rateur ferm\IeC {\'e}, 49
  \item op\IeC {\'e}rateur impulsion, 61
  \item op\IeC {\'e}rateur non born\IeC {\'e} auto-adjoint, 51
  \item op\IeC {\'e}rateur non born\IeC {\'e} sym\IeC {\'e}trique, 51
  \item op\IeC {\'e}rateur partiellement unitaire, 34
  \item op\IeC {\'e}rateur positif, 32
  \item op\IeC {\'e}rateur position, 59
  \item op\IeC {\'e}rateur pr\IeC {\'e}ferm\IeC {\'e}, 53

  \indexspace

  \item primitive d'une distribution, 144
  \item produit de convolution, 146

  \indexspace

  \item quantification de Weyl dans $L^2(\rr^{2n})$, 118
  \item quantification de Weyl polynomiale, 106

  \indexspace

  \item r\IeC {\'e}gularis\IeC {\'e}e d'une fonction, 143
  \item r\IeC {\'e}solution de l'identit\IeC {\'e}, 14
  \item r\IeC {\'e}solvante d'un op\IeC {\'e}rateur non born\IeC {\'e},
        55
  \item racine carr\IeC {\'e}e d'un op\IeC {\'e}rateur positif, 34
  \item radical d'une alg\IeC {\`e}bre de Banach, 138
  \item rayon spectral, 136
  \item relations d'incertitude, 116

  \indexspace

  \item semi-groupe continu \IeC {\`a} un param\IeC {\`e}tre, 88
  \item sous-alg\IeC {\`e}bre normale, 19
  \item spectre d'un \IeC {\'e}l\IeC {\'e}ment d'une alg\IeC {\`e}bre de Banach,
        135
  \item spectre d'un op\IeC {\'e}rateur non born\IeC {\'e}, 55
  \item spectre ponctuel, 86

  \indexspace

  \item th\IeC {\'e}or\IeC {\`e}me d'Alaoglu-Banach, 133
  \item th\IeC {\'e}or\IeC {\`e}me d'incertitude, 117
  \item th\IeC {\'e}or\IeC {\`e}me de Gelfand-Mazur, 136
  \item th\IeC {\'e}or\IeC {\`e}me de Gelfand-Na\IeC {\"\i }mark, 140
  \item th\IeC {\'e}or\IeC {\`e}me de Gelfand-Na\IeC {\"\i }mark fort,
        141
  \item th\IeC {\'e}or\IeC {\`e}me de Kato-Rellich, 73
  \item th\IeC {\'e}or\IeC {\`e}me de Radon-Nikodym, 4
  \item th\IeC {\'e}or\IeC {\`e}me de Stone, 90
  \item th\IeC {\'e}or\IeC {\`e}me de Wigner, 124
  \item th\IeC {\'e}or\IeC {\`e}me spectral fort sur les op\IeC {\'e}rateurs born\IeC {\'e}s,
        20
  \item th\IeC {\'e}or\IeC {\`e}me spectral sur les op\IeC {\'e}rateurs born\IeC {\'e}s,
        20
  \item th\IeC {\'e}or\IeC {\`e}me spectral. Cas non born\IeC {\'e}, 81
  \item topologie $*$-faible, 132
  \item topologie de Gelfand, 138
  \item topologie faible, 130
  \item trace d'un op\IeC {\'e}rateur, 46
  \item transform\IeC {\'e}e de Fourier, 68, 146
  \item transform\IeC {\'e}e de Plancherel, 156
  \item transform\IeC {\'e}es de Galil\IeC {\'e}e, 125
  \item tribu, 3

  \indexspace

  \item valeur singuli\IeC {\`e}re d'un op\IeC {\'e}rateur compact, 35
  \item variation totale, 3
  \item vecteur d'\IeC {\'e}tat, 99

\end{theindex}
```

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify: without the index, it works as expected?

Comment: **fancyhdr** works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't looked into the details but **titleps**'s manual notes that the use of `\markboth` can lead to 'unpredictable results' (page 3).

I believe that the problem is that the code for the bibliography heading does something like the following:

```
\chapter*{\bibname}
\markboth{\bibname}{\bibname}
```

The details depend on the class. For `book`, it looks like this:

```
  \defbibheading{bibliography}[\bibname]{%
    \chapter*{#1}%
    \markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
```

So, redefining the heading to avoid `\markboth`:

```
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\bibname]{%
  \chapter*{#1}}
```

should eliminate the unwanted header and footer:

[image: tidier page style]

Complete code:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Arnold,
  Title                    = {Méthodes mathématiques de la mécanique classique},
  Author                   = {Vladimir Arnold},
  Date                     = {1976},
  Publisher                = {Éditions Mir},
  Owner                    = {Bernard},
  Timestamp                = {2015.12.16}
}

@Book{DunSchw,
  Title                    = {Linear Operators, Part II},
  Author                   = {Nelson Dunford and Jacob T. G. Schwartz},
  Date                     = {1963},
  Publisher                = {Interscience Publishers},
  Owner                    = {Bernard},
  Timestamp                = {2015.12.16}
}

@Book{Hall,
  Title                    = {Quantum Theory for Mathematicians},
  Author                   = {Brian C. Hall},
  Date                     = {2013},
  Publisher                = {Springer},
  Owner                    = {Bernard},
  Timestamp                = {2015.12.16}
}

@Book{Jordan,
  Title                    = {Linear Operators for Quantum Mechanics},
  Author                   = {Thomas F. Jordan},
  Date                     = {2009},
  Publisher                = {Dover Publications, Inc.},
  Owner                    = {Bernard},
  Timestamp                = {2015.12.16}
}

@Book{Khoan,
  Title                    = {Distributions, analyse de Fourier, opérateurs aux dérivées partielles},
  Author                   = {Vo-Khac Khoan},
  Date                     = {1972},
  Publisher                = {Vuibert},
  Volume                   = {1},
  Owner                    = {Bernard},
  Timestamp                = {2015.12.16}
}

@Book{Lal,
  Title                    = {Comprenons-nous vraiment la mécanique quantique ?},
  Author                   = {Franck Laloë},
  Date                     = {2011},
  Publisher                = {EDP Sciences},
  Owner                    = {Bernard},
  Timestamp                = {2015.12.16}
}

@Book{Neu,
  Title                    = {Mathematische Grundlagen des Quantummechanick},
  Author                   = {John von Neumann},
  Date                     = {1996},
  Edition                  = {2},
  Publisher                = {Springer},
  Langid                   = {german},
  Owner                    = {Bernard},
  Timestamp                = {2015.12.16}
}

@Book{ReedSim,
  Title                    = {Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics},
  Author                   = {Michael Reed and Barry G. Simon},
  Date                     = {1972},
  Publisher                = {Academic Press},
  Owner                    = {Bernard},
  Timestamp                = {2015.12.16}
}

@Book{Rudin1,
  Title                    = {Analyse réelle et complexe},
  Author                   = {Walter Rudin},
  Date                     = {1980},
  Publisher                = {Masson},
  Owner                    = {Bernard},
  Timestamp                = {2015.12.16}
}

@Book{Rudin2,
  Title                    = {Functional Analysis},
  Author                   = {Walter Rudin},
  Date                     = {1991},
  Edition                  = {2},
  Publisher                = {McGraw-Hill, Inc.},
  Langid                    ={british},
  Owner                    = {Bernard},
  Timestamp                = {2015.12.16}
}

@Book{schwartz2,
  author =    {Laurent Schwartz},
  title =     {Théorie des distributions},
  year =      {1966},
  publisher = {Hermann},
  owner =     {Bernard},
  timestamp = {2016.01.07}
}

@Book{schwartz,
  author =    {Laurent Schwartz},
  title =     {Topologie générale et Analyse fonctionnelle},
  date =      {1970},
  publisher = {Hermann},
  owner =     {Bernard},
  timestamp = {2015.12.16}
}

@Book{VladVlad,
  Title                    = {Distributions en physique mathématique},
  Author                   = {V. Vladimirov},
  Date                     = {1979},
  Location                 = {Moscou},
  Publisher                = {Éditions Mir. Moscou, 1979},
  Owner                    = {Bernard},
  Timestamp                = {2015.12.16}
}

@Book{Wein,
  Title                    = {Lectures on Quantum Mechanics},
  Author                   = {Steven Weinberg},
  Date                     = {2013},
  Publisher                = {Cambridge University Press},
  Owner                    = {Bernard},
  Timestamp                = {2015.12.16}
}

@Article{Wigner,
  Title                    = {On Unitary Representations of the Inhomogeneous Lorentz Group},
  Author                   = {Eugene P. Wigner},
  Date                     = {1939},
  Journaltitle             = {Ann. Math.},
  Number                   = {1},
  Pages                    = {149-204},
  Series                   = {2},
  Volume                   = {40},
  Owner                    = {Bernard},
  Timestamp                = {2015.12.16}
}

@Book{Yo,
  author =    {Kôsaku Yosida},
  title =     {Functional Analysis},
  date =      {1974},
  series =    {Grundlehren der mathematischen Wissenschaften},
  number =    {123},
  publisher = {Springer},
  owner =     {Bernard},
  timestamp = {2015.12.16}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.ind}
\begin{theindex}

  \item \IeC {\'e}galit\IeC {\'e} de Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff, 107
  \item \IeC {\'e}quation de Schr\IeC {\"o}dinger, 104, 109
  \item \IeC {\'e}tat d'un syst\IeC {\`e}me, 99

  \indexspace

  \item alg\IeC {\`e}bre de Banach, 134
  \item alg\IeC {\`e}bre de Banach semi-simple, 138

  \indexspace

  \item borne essentielle, 15

  \indexspace

  \item crochet de deux op\IeC {\'e}rateurs, 107

  \indexspace

  \item d\IeC {\'e}riv\IeC {\'e}e au sens des distributions, 68, 142
  \item d\IeC {\'e}riv\IeC {\'e}e d'une mesure complexe, 7
  \item d\IeC {\'e}riv\IeC {\'e}e de Radon, 5
  \item distribution, 142

  \indexspace

  \item effondrement de la fonction d'onde, 102
  \item espaces spectraux, 24

  \indexspace

  \item famille substantielle d'ouverts, 7
  \item fermeture auto-adjointe, 54
  \item fermeture d'un op\IeC {\'e}rateur, 53
  \item fonction \IeC {\`a} variation born\IeC {\'e}e , 9
  \item fonction absolument continue , 9
  \item fonctions \IeC {\`a} d\IeC {\'e}croissance rapide, 147

  \indexspace

  \item g\IeC {\'e}n\IeC {\'e}rateur infinit\IeC {\'e}simal, 89

  \indexspace

  \item homomorphisme complexe, 135

  \indexspace

  \item id\IeC {\'e}al, id\IeC {\'e}al maximal, 136
  \item image essentielle , 15
  \item incertitude, 115
  \item int\IeC {\'e}grale de Bochner, 163
  \item involution, 134

  \indexspace

  \item lemme de Du Bois-Reymond, 144

  \indexspace

  \item mesure complexe, 3
  \item mesure complexe d\IeC {\'e}rivable, 7
  \item mesure complexe r\IeC {\'e}guli\IeC {\`e}re, 4
  \item mesure positive r\IeC {\'e}guli\IeC {\`e}re, 3
  \item mesure spectrale, 24
  \item mesures \IeC {\'e}trang\IeC {\`e}res, 4

  \indexspace

  \item norme d'une mesure complexe, 3

  \indexspace

  \item op\IeC {\'e}rateur \IeC {\'e}nergie potentielle, 60
  \item op\IeC {\'e}rateur \IeC {\`a} trace, 38
  \item op\IeC {\'e}rateur adjoint d'un op\IeC {\'e}rateur non born\IeC {\'e},
        50
  \item op\IeC {\'e}rateur compact, 30
  \item op\IeC {\'e}rateur de Hilbert-Schmidt, 42, 121
  \item op\IeC {\'e}rateur de quantification, 65
  \item op\IeC {\'e}rateur de Schr\IeC {\"o}dinger, 72
  \item op\IeC {\'e}rateur dens\IeC {\'e}ment d\IeC {\'e}fini, 50
  \item op\IeC {\'e}rateur essentiellement auto-adjoint, 54
  \item op\IeC {\'e}rateur ferm\IeC {\'e}, 49
  \item op\IeC {\'e}rateur impulsion, 61
  \item op\IeC {\'e}rateur non born\IeC {\'e} auto-adjoint, 51
  \item op\IeC {\'e}rateur non born\IeC {\'e} sym\IeC {\'e}trique, 51
  \item op\IeC {\'e}rateur partiellement unitaire, 34
  \item op\IeC {\'e}rateur positif, 32
  \item op\IeC {\'e}rateur position, 59
  \item op\IeC {\'e}rateur pr\IeC {\'e}ferm\IeC {\'e}, 53

  \indexspace

  \item primitive d'une distribution, 144
  \item produit de convolution, 146

  \indexspace

  \item quantification de Weyl dans $L^2(\rr^{2n})$, 118
  \item quantification de Weyl polynomiale, 106

  \indexspace

  \item r\IeC {\'e}gularis\IeC {\'e}e d'une fonction, 143
  \item r\IeC {\'e}solution de l'identit\IeC {\'e}, 14
  \item r\IeC {\'e}solvante d'un op\IeC {\'e}rateur non born\IeC {\'e},
        55
  \item racine carr\IeC {\'e}e d'un op\IeC {\'e}rateur positif, 34
  \item radical d'une alg\IeC {\`e}bre de Banach, 138
  \item rayon spectral, 136
  \item relations d'incertitude, 116

  \indexspace

  \item semi-groupe continu \IeC {\`a} un param\IeC {\`e}tre, 88
  \item sous-alg\IeC {\`e}bre normale, 19
  \item spectre d'un \IeC {\'e}l\IeC {\'e}ment d'une alg\IeC {\`e}bre de Banach,
        135
  \item spectre d'un op\IeC {\'e}rateur non born\IeC {\'e}, 55
  \item spectre ponctuel, 86

  \indexspace

  \item th\IeC {\'e}or\IeC {\`e}me d'Alaoglu-Banach, 133
  \item th\IeC {\'e}or\IeC {\`e}me d'incertitude, 117
  \item th\IeC {\'e}or\IeC {\`e}me de Gelfand-Mazur, 136
  \item th\IeC {\'e}or\IeC {\`e}me de Gelfand-Na\IeC {\"\i }mark, 140
  \item th\IeC {\'e}or\IeC {\`e}me de Gelfand-Na\IeC {\"\i }mark fort,
        141
  \item th\IeC {\'e}or\IeC {\`e}me de Kato-Rellich, 73
  \item th\IeC {\'e}or\IeC {\`e}me de Radon-Nikodym, 4
  \item th\IeC {\'e}or\IeC {\`e}me de Stone, 90
  \item th\IeC {\'e}or\IeC {\`e}me de Wigner, 124
  \item th\IeC {\'e}or\IeC {\`e}me spectral fort sur les op\IeC {\'e}rateurs born\IeC {\'e}s,
        20
  \item th\IeC {\'e}or\IeC {\`e}me spectral sur les op\IeC {\'e}rateurs born\IeC {\'e}s,
        20
  \item th\IeC {\'e}or\IeC {\`e}me spectral. Cas non born\IeC {\'e}, 81
  \item topologie $*$-faible, 132
  \item topologie de Gelfand, 138
  \item topologie faible, 130
  \item trace d'un op\IeC {\'e}rateur, 46
  \item transform\IeC {\'e}e de Fourier, 68, 146
  \item transform\IeC {\'e}e de Plancherel, 156
  \item transform\IeC {\'e}es de Galil\IeC {\'e}e, 125
  \item tribu, 3

  \indexspace

  \item valeur singuli\IeC {\`e}re d'un op\IeC {\'e}rateur compact, 35
  \item variation totale, 3
  \item vecteur d'\IeC {\'e}tat, 99

\end{theindex}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper] {book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{makeidx, amsfonts}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}

\usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=authortitle]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\defbibheading{bibliography}[\bibname]{%
  \chapter*{#1}}

\makeindex

\newcommand\rr{\mathbb{R}}
\newpagestyle{bibps}{%
\sethead[\thepage][][\bfseries Bibliography]{\bfseries Bibliography}{}{\thepage}%
\setfoot{}{}{}%
}
\newpagestyle{idxps}{%
\sethead[\thepage][][\scshape Index]{\scshape Index}{}{\thepage}
\setfoot{}{}{}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A First Chapter}

\[ \bar{D}\mu(x) = \lim_{r\to 0}\bar{\Delta}_{r}(x) = \inf_{r}\,\sup\Bigl\{\frac{\mu(E)}{m(E)}; x \in E, \delta E < r \Bigr\} . \]%

\chapter{A Second Chapter}

\lipsum[1-10]

\cite{Rudin1,Rudin2}

\cleardoublepage
\nocite{*}
\pagestyle{bibps}
\printbibliography

\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{idxps}
\printindex

\clearpage
\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution, milady! I knew about `\markboth` and `titleps`.

Comment: Actually your solution partly solved my real problem. What remained was the following: I redefined `\pagenumbering` for `plain` style as `scroman` (a personal style,, in order to get the old (French?) style, where roman numbering uses old-style numbers, and I set this style for the front matter. However, the index, at the end, used again this ols-style numbering, and I concluded that `makeindex` sets `\pagenumbering` to `plain`, but wasn't able to find where it was so defined – I suppose in `latex.ltx` Do you happen to know where the index page style is defined?

Comment: To be honest, it is a bit difficult to think about it without an example ;). How do you prevent that numbering being used each time a chapter is started? In `book`, for example, the first page of every chapter uses the `plain` page style, doesn't it? So you've stopped that? Or redefined it? [I figured you would know about the `\markboth`/`titleps` thing if I found it on page 3, but I thought it best to include that in my answer so that it might make sense to other people.]

Comment: As I redefine the formatting of chapters, sections, &c. , with titlesec, I incorporate a `\thispagestyle{empty}` in `\titleformat{\chapter}`. As for my old-style numbering, I simply used a  personal page style with `\clearpage\pagestyle{\myps}` after my `\frontmatter`. B.t.w., I find `titleps` much easier to use than `fancyhdr`.

Comment: `theindex` does `\thispagestyle{plain}`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: It is. But I solved my problem: initially, to set  page numbering to old style, I redefined the plain style, as I didn't know  the index uses the plain style. It was enough to define an `osplain`  style instead and use it for the front matter.